# Linux Live CD: Flash preinstalled?

Tags: linux, flash, livecd, flash-player, compact-disc

I need to create a Linux Live CD that has the newest version of Flash pre-installed.  How can I do this or find a distro with this?

The flavor of Linux doesn’t matter, so long as I can run Flash and a web browser…

EDIT: I do not have an existing installation of Linux to work with, and I am a Linux novice...

Comment: Making your own Linux without Linux already installed is slightly tricky as no one sees a real need to port their tools to other operating systems.

Comment: If they let you add a custom repo then it may work. Otherwise, no.

Comment: The .repo file in the package would tell you where the repo is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a program called Remastersys that will allow you to turn your existing Ubuntu installation into a live cd. So just install Ubuntu with everything you like and use Remastersys to turn it into a live cd.

Tutorial here:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html
http://klikit.pbworks.com/Remastersys+tutorial+by+dedoimedo

Downloadable here:
http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/remastersystool.html

Comment: with some workarounds, I got it to work...

Comment: @studiohack Good! Do you think you can briefly tell us what workarounds had to be taken?

Comment: @BloodPhilia: when i followed the guide in the first URL, i ran into problems on the command line.  The 2nd tutorial is more GUI based, but was written for Ubuntu 8.10 - I used 10.10.  Using the new Software Manager, I found it, and installed it, then followed the 2nd half of the tutorial (regarding the actual use of the program).  Not sure yet how it will work if it is above 700 MB (the size of my CDs).

Answer (score 2):

If you add the [Adobe yum repo](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) and use an appropriate kickstart file then you can [build a Fedora live CD/USB image](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD) that has it included.