# How to create reusable Ubuntu image

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop and configured a lot, installed and setup lot of things on it to suit my needs. Now I want to move this setup to another machine and want to avoid all the setup again. Is there a way I can create an installer out of my existing Ubuntu installation/partition which I can reuse for other machines ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/).  Using it, you can create a custom Live CD of your Ubuntu installation and install it other places...

> 1. It can make a full system backup including personal data to a live cd or dvd that you can use anywhere and install.
> 2. It can make a distributable copy you can share with friends.  This will not have any of your personal user data in it.

I have used this myself, recently, and it took some figuring out, but once you install it, everything else is a breeze...*highly recommend!*

In fact, see this answer here: [Linux Live CD: Flash preinstalled?](https://superuser.com/questions/206357/linux-live-cd-flash-preinstalled/206363#206363) - the 2nd tutorial in the answer (by [BloodPhilia](https://superuser.com/users/34844/bloodphilia)) I linked is the best one...Since you are using Ubuntu 10.10, it is pretty easy...do the step where you add the Remastersys to the repository, then go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for Remastersys.  Next install it, then proceed to open Remastersys and follow the instructions regarding backing up your system...

Any questions, just ask!